# How to pass strings stored in variables to find command

Tags: command-line, bash, find

I need to pass strings stored in a variable to a find command string.

What I do:

```
s="\( ! -path \"/path/to/1/Recycle Bin\" \) -or"
s="${s} \( ! -path \"/path/to/2/Recycle Bin\" \)"
exec=$(find "/path/to/Recycle Bin" -type d $s)
```

Result:

```
find: paths must precede expression: `\('
```

If I do:

```
exec=$(find "/path/to/Recycle Bin" -type d \( ! -path "/path/to/1/Recycle Bin" \) -or \( ! -path "/path/to/2/Recycle Bin" \))
```

It works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your using two `s` variables?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen If I will use various variables error doesn't vanish.

Comment: Any attempt to use strings will almost inevitably either split words where you don't want it to, or not split words where you do - the only reliable solution is to create an *array* of arguments and pass it with quoting as `"${myarray[@]}"`

Comment: @steeldriver Same problem... :(

Comment: @Zanna I can't see your post. Do you delete your post? IMHO it shows the problem. It is a good post.

Comment: Oh thanks Bob. I thought my post was an incomplete answer, I just put it there to help you examine what was going on and deleted it because you got a more useful answer. Since you mentioned it being helpful I put it back. Thanks :)

Comment: @Zanna It is an incomplete answer, but IMHO it is the very useful answer. It helps to show what problem. For example, I don't know command `set -x`, but I am not professional in Linux. :) Unfortunately, I have not reputation vote for your post. By the way, I decide this question. I was forced to delete all symbols (as you said) and rename directory (without space).

Comment: :) happy to help and glad you found a workaround at least!

Comment: @Zanna However I think It can run with the spaced directory, but I have no knowledge. I am junior in Ubuntu. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the only reliable to do this in bash is to make use of an array.

Properly quoted arrays allow you to construct a command line that consists of individually parsable arguments that may contain whitespace.

Ex.

```
$ a=( find "/path/to/Recycle Bin" -type d )
$ a+=( \( ! -path "/path/to/1/Recycle Bin" )
$ a+=( -or ! -path "/path/to/2/Recycle Bin" \) )
```

We can see what the shell will see by printing out the individual elements, one per line:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"
find
/path/to/Recycle Bin
-type
d
(
!
-path
/path/to/1/Recycle Bin
-or
!
-path
/path/to/2/Recycle Bin
)
```

Comment: I can combine any elements to a line, however, I need combine in command (NOT text or line). I want to execute variable consist of command. My problem in combine a variable, when I combine commanded variable (var `exec` in my case) I get a error. Why? @Zanna explained to me.

Comment: But any case thanks for your help. I am thinking abount problem. I glad any help.

Comment: @Bob you can execute the resulting command with all its arguments by writing `"${a[@]}"` - the quotes are important

Comment: It really works... Thanks. :) If I have understood your script early, I have needed to rename the directory and reconfigure programme. I save your script in my library. Also, I have the question, where can I read information about construction `var=(...)` . How do it call?

Answer (score 1):

If your variable might not contain what you think it does, use

```
set -x
```

to see the result of each expansion.

The shell processes the backslashes and double quotes in `find` commands, but it's not processing them the same way when it expands your variable...

On the command line, we write:

```
find "/path/to/Recycle Bin" -type d \( ! -path "/path/to/1/Recycle Bin" \) -or \( ! -path "/path/to/2/Recycle Bin" \)
```

If you've run `set -x`, you can see what Bash makes of that and what's actually passed to `find`:

```
+ find '/path/to/Recycle Bin' -type d '(' '!' -path '/path/to/1/Recycle Bin' ')' -or '(' '!' -path '/path/to/2/Recycle Bin' ')'
```

Quote removal on your variable doesn't happen (you put the `\` and `"` characters in there, so you want them kept, right? These character have "resulted from the expansion" so they are [not removed](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quote-Removal)) (`\"` became `"` when you assigned it as you presumably intended because in double quotes backslash quotes the chars `` \$`" ``), but wordsplitting does:

```
$ find "/path/to/Recycle Bin" -type d $s
+ find '/path/to/Recycle Bin' -type d '\(' '!' -path '"/path/to/1/Recycle' 'Bin"' '\)' -or '\(' '!' -path '"/path/to/2/Recycle' 'Bin"' '\)'
find: paths must precede expression: \(
```

Quoting the variable fixes the bad word splitting but also prevents [tokenisation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Operation):

```
$ find "/path/to/Recycle Bin" -type d "$s"
+ find '/path/to/Recycle Bin' -type d '\( ! -path "/path/to/1/Recycle Bin" \) -or \( ! -path "/path/to/2/Recycle Bin" \)'
find: paths must precede expression: \( ! -path "/path/to/1/Recycle Bin" \) -or \( ! -path "/path/to/2/Recycle Bin" \)
```

Pretty much anything you do with these two strings is going to result in `find` seeing the wrong thing. Getting your variable to contain only and exactly a string that expands to `'(' '!' -path '/path/to/1/Recycle Bin' ')' -or '(' '!' -path '/path/to/2/Recycle Bin' ')'` is a quote war I personally couldn't win.

Something like this will work fine

```
s="/path/to/1/Recycle Bin"
t="/path/to/2/Recycle Bin"
find "/path/to/Recycle Bin" -type d \( ! -path "$s" \) -or \( ! -path "$t" \)
```

You can also get away with it if you remove the need for quoting by not using paths with spaces - if you take out the backslashes and double quotes:

```
s="( ! -path /path/to/1/Trash ) -or"
s="${s} ( ! -path /path/to/2/Trash )"
find /path/to/Trash -type d $s
```

Maybe if you explain why you want to do it this way someone can suggest a better workaround.

Comment: I see... `'\(' '!' -path '"/path/to/1/Recycle' 'Bin"' '\)'` - Bash understand as two arguments ("/path/to/1/Recycle" and "Bin"). Interestingly, if I rename the directory to "Trash" will it run? I will test tomorrow. But it is not desirable result to me. It will means to me that I will have to reconfigure all programs.

Comment: @Bob no, that won't fix it because you have unwanted backslashes and double quotes seen by `find`. The shell removes them on the command line, but not from the variable. But if you remove the backslashes and double quotes, it will work. Maybe I will edit my answer later if I find a better way